# Please merge and/or close all similar questions that request recommendations answered by our Reading List?

Tags: discussion

Don't hesitate at all to edit this post, if you find other duplicates or similarities.

Don't these duplicate each other?

[Basic background reading request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/21566), [Any solid textbook recommendations to begin studying linguistics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12371).

These don't exactly duplicate, but definitely overlap.

[Studying Linguistics for a Programmer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/4670), [Book suggestions for linguistics for Computer Science people](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9880).

[Textbook suggestions for syntax, semantics/pragmatics and phonetics/phonology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3344), [Book suggestions for linguistics for Computer Science people](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9880).

Our Reading List answers these questions.

[What are some good books on word formation and semantics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/39121)
[What are the best books to study Phonology at an introductory level?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/27954)
[Books recommendation on syntax, semantics and pragmatics interaction](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/38150)
[What books to read about lexical semantics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/29860)

Comment: Or just purge them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these questions I totally missed so thanks for gathering them, I have closed most of them because as user6726 says, asking for lists is way too broad. We used to accept them, kind of, to increase our question count a bit at the beginning but they only lower the quality of the website.

I will leave the Wiki one open and some others that where not just asking for lists.

Answer (score 3):

I still maintain that a cat is not a dog, even if they are similar. "Duplicate" has a special status on SE: it's a reason to close a question. Usually, questions are closed as dupes when an older question contains all of the information necessary to answer the instant question. Of your intro-text questions, the newer question (potential dupe) is much more specific as to what kind of book is sought. It is interesting that one of the answers to the earlier question is better as an answer to the later question, but still, the question is not a dupe.

A more serious problem with textbook questions is that (1) they tend to be way too broad, asking for huge lists (not supposed to ask list questions on SE) and (2) they are usually calls for opinions ("what's the best syntax textbook?").